# How to get a specific sql command result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables (Commands, Clients) which are as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE COMMANDES (
NO_COMMANDE NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
CODE_CLIENT CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
NO_EMPLOYE NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
DATE_COM DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
DATE_ENV DATE,
PRIX_TOT NUMBER(7,2) );

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYES (
NO_EMPLOYE NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
NOM  CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRENOM CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DATE_NAISSANCE  DATE NOT NULL,
FONCTION  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
DATE_ENTREE  DATE NOT NULL
);
```

And, I want to make a SQL command that allows me to get something like this.

[image]

does anyone have any idea how to do this, Please?

Comment: where are you running this code? If SQL*Plus then this looks very much like a sqlplus report https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081534

Comment: it is actually Sqlplus report, but first I just want to view the table on SQL*plus before put it into a report.

Comment: So you have the SQL*plus report already? share your SQL and tell us what's not working

Comment: ... to get something like this? Something like WHAT? I don't see a thing!

Comment: Although you can do such things in sqlplus, I would suggest you to pass your query output as a `CURSOR` to a Java / Python / Perl application and do such formatting there.